# Google Dataflow: Cannot read and write in different locations BigQuery - Python

Tags: python, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753904/bigquery-dataflow-error-cannot-read-and-write-in-different-locations-while-read) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42135002/google-dataflow-cannot-read-and-write-in-different-locations-python-sdk-v0-5-5) the problem should be fixed, isn't?

What I'm doing:

```
| 'Read' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(
                    query='SELECT * FROM XXX.YYY', use_standard_sql=True))
```

What I get:

```
Cannot read and write in different locations: source: EU, destination: US
```

What I've tried:

- [Specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46753904/bigquery-dataflow-error-cannot-read-and-write-in-different-locations-while-read)  the zone in pipeline_options:

  ```
      pipeline_options.view_as(WorkerOptions).zone = 'europe-west1'
  ```
- [Use](https://github.com/apache/beam/pull/6463) dryRun:

But none of them solved the problem.

EXTRA:

If you use:

```
| 'Read' >> beam.io.Read(beam.io.BigQuerySource(
                 table='XXX:YYY.Table'))
```

You can get the result without problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed updating the google-cloud-bigquery python package